# Converting ordering via date and time php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, strtotime

I have 3 tables of data stored in a database each containing a date and a time field. I'm pulling all the relevant data from each table and concatenating them to an array. I now need to sort the array on date first and then time. I'm currently sorting by date at that works fine but the time sometimes can be right and is sometimes wrong

What I'm currently using to gather the data:

```
$results = [];

$sql_assign = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tk_assign` WHERE ticket_id = $tk_id");
$sql_update = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tk_update` WHERE ticket_id = $tk_id");
$sql_status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tk_status_change` WHERE ticket_id = $tk_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_assign)){
     $results[] = $row;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_update)){
     $results[] = $row;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_status)){
     $results[] = $row;
}
```

What I'm using to sort it

```
$orderByDate = $my2 = array();
foreach($results as $key=>$row)
{
    $my2 = explode('/',$row['date']);
    $my3 = explode('/',$row['time']);
    $my_date2 = $my2[1].'/'.$my2[0].'/'.$my2[2];
    $orderByDate[$key] = strtotime($my_date2);  
}    
$sorted = array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $results);
```

I've thought about turning it into timecodes but that hasn't worked either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Example time and date:

```
Date: 22/09/2015 Time: 15:32:12
Date: 22/09/2015 Time: 14:50:28
Date: 25/09/2015 Time: 12:21:58
```

Comment: Can you please post sample date and time values?

Comment: Added some to the question. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just `ORDER BY` in the SQL query itself??

Comment: because the data is coming from 3 different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

```
$my3 = explode('/',$row['time']);
```

It probably should be:

```
$my3 = explode(':',$row['time']);
```

In any case, you're not even using the `$my3` variable in your sorting algorithm.

Here's another solution. Just after merging the arrays, add the following code:

```
for ($i =0; $i < count($results); $i++){
    $results[$i]['datetime'] = $results[$i]['date'].' '.$results[$i]['time'];
}   

function compareDateTime($a, $b) {
    $mya = new DateTime();
    $mya->createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $a['datetime']);

    $myb = new DateTime();
    $myb->createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $b['datetime']);

    if ($mya == $myb)
        return 0;
    if ($mya > $myb)
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

usort($results, 'compareDateTime');
```

Comment: I get the following error: Warning: usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function

Comment: Still getting the same error. It also says: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (22/09/2015 15:32:12) at position 0 (2):

Comment: Could you try the edited solution now? Let's see if that works. Note: please copy and paste all the code as the variable names have changed.

Comment: Remove the part of your code starting with foreach... . You don't need it anymore.

Comment: Sorry- how would I reverse the order. I've tried changing the $mya > $myb to $mya < $myb

Comment: At the end, add the following code `$results = array_reverse($results);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PHP > 5.2` then you should use following way.

```
$orderByDate = $my2 = array();
foreach($results as $key=>$row)
{
    $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
    $orderByDate[$key] = strtotime($newDateString." ".$row['time']);  
}    
$sorted = array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $results);
```